# Нужны ли кавычки: «без раскачки»?

Tags: кавычки

В России политической год начался «без раскачки».
Нужны ли кавычки?

Comment: Времени на раскачку, как я уже говорил,  нет. (с) ВВП

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки нужны для совмещения формального стиля (политический год) с неформальным ("раскачка"), только предлог в кавычки не нужно брать.